# How can I write take the output of the html code below and add it to my php response?

Tags: php, sql, html, drag-and-drop

I know how to work with fields and buttons in a form. 
But how do i use this kinda code http://www.useragentman.com/tests/dragAndDrop/permissionForm.html
and use its values with html or php. 
Basically, how do tell what name has put in which field in code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will require a significant amount of JavaScript AJAX code to interface with PHP.  When an item is dropped onto a target, a JavaScript function bound to the item's `drop` event is called.  That function must then initiate an AJAX call which passes the contents of the dragged item and an identifier of the target box (where it was dropped) up to a PHP script on the server.

[The companion page](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/01/10/cross-browser-html5-drag-and-drop/) has a few code examples for handling the javascript. But you will need to read up quite a bit on AJAX before attempting to use this with PHP.

Comment: Im not married to php. how do i get to write the JS variables to my SQL. Im a little short on time. So, its fine with me if its a little dirty

Comment: @Joubin You cannot write directly from JS to MySQL - there must be a server-side script (PHP, python, etc) in between to intercept the HTTP request and interface with the database.